# Cut a part of background image and drag it as an object in fabric JS

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am drawing a `rectangle` by using `fabric js` with `mousemove` . I want to cut a part of background Image of `canvas` which comes inside the area of `rectangle` and then get the cut part of image as an `object` and paste it anywhere else on canvas. It is like dragging that cut part.

I tried to do it with `clipPath`:

```
var marq_rect, isDown, origX, origY, marqer;

canvas.on('mouse:down', function (o) {
    isDown = true;
    canvas.set({ 'selection': false });
    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    origX = pointer.x;
    origY = pointer.y;
    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    marq_rect = new fabric.Rect({
        left: origX,
        top: origY,
        originX: 'left',
        originY: 'top',
        width: pointer.x - origX,
        height: pointer.y - origY,
        angle: 0,
        fill: 'transparent',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeDashArray: [2, 2],
        strokeDashOffset: 20,
        strokeWidth: 2,
        transparentCorners: false,
        id: 'marq_rect'
   });
                                
   canvas.add(marq_rect);

   canvas.on('mouse:move', function (o) {
       if (!isDown) return;
       var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);

       if (origX > pointer.x) {
           marq_rect.set({ left: Math.abs(pointer.x) });
       }
       if (origY > pointer.y) {
           marq_rect.set({ top: Math.abs(pointer.y) });
       }

       marq_rect.set({ width: Math.abs(origX - pointer.x) });
       marq_rect.set({ height: Math.abs(origY - pointer.y) });
       
       canvas.requestRenderAll();
  });

  canvas.on('mouse:up', function (o) {
     isDown = false;
     canvas.set({ 'selection': true });
     bg_image.clipPath = marq_rect;
     canvas.requestRenderAll();
  });
```

**It should look like this:**

[image]

You can see that part of image inside the `rect` is cut out and can be dragged.
**It can also be a circle or any other shape instead of rect.**
Thanks in advance.